# Does it make any difference using http when referring to assets?

Tags: php, html, web-applications, web, laravel

So i'm building a webpage.  I want to put a glorious picture somewhere.  I will of course use an img tag, but I'm curious if it makes any difference if I do this:

```
<img src="img/mypic.png">
```

versus this:

```
<img src="http://www.mysite.com/img/mypic.png">
```

Either one will display the image, but I'm curious about performance.  Does the client browser care which method is used?  I imagine that A would be faster, based on a guess that it process the request "internally", and thus must be faster...

Does the server *always* send a request a request back over the internet with method B?

Given the option is available, is one better than another?

You see, my thinking is to run multiple subdomains, some of which may completely be transferred away later.  Rather than duplicate assets, I want to continue managing them from my 'central asset repository', if you will.  If I had thousands of users, at what point do I need to be concerned about performance between these 2 methods?

Any other advice on managing assets, or best practices to consider?

Comment: Relative paths are preferred where applicable because they will still work if the site is moved to another domain (assuming the file structure remains unchanged, of course).

Comment: Neither will have a noticeable effect on performance, if it has an effect at all. But if you go with the first one, please use a slash in front: `<img src="/img/mypic.png">`, because currently it will only work correctly on the root page.

Comment: You can avoid preslashing everything with a simple <base> tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best practice using laravel is

```
{{ URL::to_asset('files/image.jpg') }}
```

this will generate an absolute URL based on your `config/application.php` settings. e.g.

```
http://myapp.com/files/image.jpg
```

This approach uses the laravel environnements and is very flexible in case you are moving your assets to a CDN or on a different server or subdomain. All URLs are configurable with one line in the config file.

In terms of speed it doesn't make a difference if your are using absolute or relative paths, as the browser is capable of processing URLs very fast.

Comment: just to clarify, presume the forward slash is still preferred, e.g.to_asset('/files/image.jpg')?  also, in the situation Orangepill described, couldn't I just update laravel's config/app to https?

Comment: If you use to_asset, laravel will add the configured asset path, so a prefixed slash is not needed. Yes obviously, just change the config and you have https urls.

Answer (score 3):

I would say **never** use `http` when accessing assets on your own domain. Speed has little or nothing to do with the reasoning for this. Why this is done is because when you introduce ssl onto a domain everywhere you are using `http` has to change to `https` at least for the connections that where established over `https`.  Some browser either complain loudly or flat out refuse to download unsecure assets when connecting over https. So follow these guidelines

When you are creating an app that does any rewrites and a page can be accessed from more then one "directory" within your site or you want to use a common header or layout template throughout your site then prefer this format:

```
/path/to/asset.js   - this is an absolute path
```

over

```
path/to/asset.js    - this is a relative path
```

the only time this isn't true is when you are referencing assets in css as those assests are loaded relative to the css, but the css itself will should be loaded with the leading '/'

and when accessing external assets (js loaded on cdn) prefer:

```
//example.com/path/to/asset.js  (works if the site support both http & https will request it however the hosting page was requested this is called a protocol relative path )
```

over

```
http://example.com/path/to/asset.js
```